# Moving from web browser control to web view 2 control - how to update previous code

Tags: vb.net, winforms, webbrowser-control, webview2

I was using an old web browser control (net framework 4.5) and now I want to use the web view 2 because I need to not use Internet Explorer anymore.
Previously I was searching the document in web browser to get some values from the page, like this:

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_NavigatingAsync(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.Navigating
        Try
            Dim AllElementes As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.All


            For Each webpageelement As HtmlElement In AllElementes
                If webpageelement.GetAttribute("id") = "btnDownload" Then
                    Application.Restart()
                    Environment.Exit(0)
                End If
                If webpageelement.GetAttribute("id") = "txtUser" Then
                    Dim user = webpageelement.GetAttribute("value")
                    If Len(user) > 0 Then
                        My.Settings.user = user.ToString
                    End If
                End If
                If webpageelement.GetAttribute("id") = "txtPassword" Then
                    Dim password = webpageelement.GetAttribute("value")
                    If Len(password) > 0 Then
                        My.Settings.password = password.ToString
                    End If
                End If
                My.Settings.Save()
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub
```

How can I do the same with web view 2? I see that it doesn't have a document property so I can't do webview21.document.all

Comment: WebView2 doesn't expose the DOM in its API. Instead you can inject script to interact with those same DOM APIs via JavaScript using the CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync method. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.executescriptasync?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.961.33#Microsoft_Web_WebView2_Core_CoreWebView2_ExecuteScriptAsync_System_String_

Comment: @DavidRisney ok, some idea of what is the correspondant event of WebBrowser1_Navigating for Webview2? I want to search for elements when a webpage is loaded. Thanks

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/navigation-events for info on navigation events. DOMContentLoaded event will be raised when the DOM has been parsed and NavigationCompleted will be raised when body.onload in the DOM would be raised which is after all subdownloads (CSS, script, images, frames) are done loading as well.